Prisma: how to use IN with two params in queryRaw?
Documentation says:
const ids = [1, 3, 5, 10, 20];
const result = await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM User WHERE id IN (${Prisma.join(ids)})`;

It works.
But how to follow this way with two params in IN?
SQL for example:
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (param1, param2) IN (('str1', 'str2'), ('str3', 'str4'));

Thanks.
